# Sequelize Where clause with optional params

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, sequelize.js

How do I write Sequelize queries with optional params? 
Let's say, I have a following query:

```
        const result : SomeModel[] = await SomeModel.findAll(
                {where: 
                    {
                        id: givenId,
                        type: someType
                    }
                });
```

How do I rephrase the same query in case someType is null?
If someType is null, then it should be removed from the where clause and results should be return only on basis of 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the where clause outside...

```
let where = { id: givenId };

if(someType)
    where.type = someType;
```

...and using it in your query like so

```
await SomeModel.findAll({where});
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of this too. It works!
But was looking for something tidier.